# jetpack compose navController popBackStack Multiple pages

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I have three pages A, B and C, which are accessed sequentially through navigation.

A -> B -> C

How can I return from C to A?

These official descriptions should be useful, but don’t understand.

```
// Pop everything up to the "home" destination off the back stack before
// navigating to the "friends" destination
navController.navigate(“friends”) {
    popUpTo("home")
}

// Pop everything up to and including the "home" destination off
// the back stack before navigating to the "friends" destination
navController.navigate("friends") {
    popUpTo("home") { inclusive = true }
}

// Navigate to the "search” destination only if we’re not already on
// the "search" destination, avoiding multiple copies on the top of the
// back stack
navController.navigate("search") {
    launchSingleTop = true
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The navigation you are referring to shows how to clear the stack when navigating to a specific destination.

If you need to clear the navigation stack, you can use [popBackStack](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/NavController#popBackStack(kotlin.String,kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.Boolean)) as shown below:

```
navController.popBackStack(route = "A", inclusive = false)
```

Comment: Very cool, simple and effective, you always have a solution, do you have the question first or the answer first?

Comment: what if I want use `popBackStack` with arguments?

Comment: This is working only when the route has no arguments otherwise It fails. How can I resolve this

Comment: @MohammadBaqer did you find out the solution

Comment: @EmmanuelMtali sadly i didnt find the solution and I ended up using same viewModel for  my two screens to share data between them

Comment: @MohammadBaqer you need to specify route with placeholder, here, e.g. "yourRoute/{yourArgumentName}", not with the replaced argument. If you have multiple items of the same route with different arguments, you can do while block, checking current `currentBackStackEntry` and calling `navController.popBackStack()` until you pop all the needed routes

Comment: I developed a method to help when having arguments, here it is: ```internal fun String.attachNavArgs(navArgs: List<NamedNavArgument>) =
    (navArgs.joinToString(prefix = this + QUESTION_MARK, separator = ",") { "${it.name}={${it.name}}" })```

Answer (score 0):

Well I have done it with the following approach. I am using the new [navigation guide 2022](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-type-safety)

```
// --- Screen

@Composable 
fun A() {
        
}

// --- Navigation

const val aRoute = "a_route"

fun NavController.navigateToA(navOptions = NavOptions?) {
    this.navigate(aRoute, navOptions)
}

fun NavGraphBuilder.aScreen() {
    composable(route = aRoute) {
        A()
    }
}
```

Whenever you want to navigate to A you use the following

```
// Navigate without popping anything
navController.navigateToA() 

// Navigate pop to A launchSingleTop will prevent A - A stuck on top of each other
navController.navigateToA(
    navOptions {
        popUpTo(aRoute)
        launchSingleTop = true
    }
)
```